# CRUD Node.Js SQL server

Tags: nodejs, express, postman, mssql

Estoy haciendo una API la cual es un CRUD de *Node* con *SQLServer*, para la conexión esto ocupando la Api de *mssql*, en la parte de las rutas establecí la siguiente:

```
router.get('/products/:category', getProductsCategoria);
```

Esta ruta me manda a llamar un método que tengo en mi controlador el cual quiero que mediante parámetros o *Body* me tome el valor para asignarlo a una consulta con *WHERE*.

```
export const getProductsCategoria = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const { category } = req.params;
    
        const pool = await getConnection();
        const result = await pool
            .request()
            .input('category', category)
            .query(queries.getProductByCat);
        
        res.send(result.recordset[0]);
        
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500);
        res.send(error.message);
    }
};
```

El query que mando a llamar en el método es el siguiente:

```
getProductByCat: 'SELECT * FROM Products WHERE category = @category',
```

Por ultimo hago la prueba en *Postman*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me arroja el siguiente error:

> ```
> (node:15192) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'HARDWARE' to data type int.
>     at handleError (C:\Users\NESTOR\Desktop\Projects\sysware\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:388:15)
>     at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
>     at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
>     at Connection.emit (C:\Users\NESTOR\Desktop\Projects\sysware\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1071:18)
>     at Parser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NESTOR\Desktop\Projects\sysware\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1176:12)
>     at Parser.emit (events.js:315:20)
>     at Parser.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
>     at Readable.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NESTOR\Desktop\Projects\sysware\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:27:14)
>     at Readable.emit (events.js:315:20)
>     at Readable.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> (node:15192) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:15192) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
> ```

¿Cómo le puedo hacer para que me tome ese valor y agregarlo a la clausula *Where*?

Gracias.

Comment: El código y el error deben ir como texto por favor. ;)

Comment: Gracias por el tip, ya edite mi pregunta